# Can Storm Sphere's bonus action be used on the same turn the spell is cast?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, actions

I am wondering whether one could cast [Storm Sphere](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/storm-sphere) as an action, and in the same turn immediately follow it up with the spell's bonus action to deal more damage.

I have a feeling this doesn't work, going by the PHB's rule on [bonus-action spells](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#BonusAction) (emphasis mine):

> A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You must use a bonus action on your turn to cast the spell, provided that you haven't already taken a bonus action this turn. **You can't cast another spell during the same turn**, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action. (PHB, p. 202)

But I wanted to check and make sure, in case there's a slim chance the wording intends to mean if you begin a turn with a bonus action, you can't follow the bonus action up with a non-cantrip spell.

Comment: Storm Sphere is not _cast_ with a bonus action, that whole section from the PHB is irrelevant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### You can use it

The rule on bonus action spells only applies to casting new spells, not the actions or bonus actions enabled by spells. As long as *storm sphere* is active, you can use it's effect as a bonus action. This in no way restricts your spellcasting as it is not actually casting a bonus action spell.